# What were the other standing-orders of the Grand Army of the Republic?

Tags: star-wars

Other than "*Order 66*", what other hidden directives were there hidden within the clones inhibitor chips?

Presumably there had to be some way of disguising it amongst other inconspicuous orders so as not to reveal it to the Jedi?

Comment: "Order 1: you do not talk about Order 66!  Order 2: you do not talk about Order 66!"

Comment: Orders 1-65: Don't kill Jedi. Order 66: Ok, kill Jedi. Orders 67-100: Definitely don't kill Jedi.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. The standing orders were *openly* communicated. The inhibitor chip was simply there to generate blind loyalty.

Comment: @Richard yeah, i was getting hung up from another question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [Known Contingency Orders](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Contingency_Orders_for_the_Grand_Army_of_the_Republic:_Order_Initiation,_Orders_1_Through_150) :

*Obviously we're missing a few here...*

> - **Order 4**: "In the event of the Supreme Commander (Chancellor) being incapacitated, overall GAR command shall fall to the vice chair of the Senate until a successor is appointed or alternative authority identified as outlined in Section 6 (iv)."
> - **Order 5**: "In the event of the Supreme Commander (Chancellor) being declared unfit to issue orders, as defined in Section 6 (ii), the Chief of the Defense Staff shall assume GAR command and form a strategic cell of senior officers (see page 1173, para 4) until a successor is appointed or alternative authority identified."
> - **Order 37**: Capture of a single wanted individual through the mass arrest and threatened execution of a civilian population. Follow-up directives include scenarios for body disposal of civilian casualties and suppression of communications.
> - **Order 65**: "In the event of either (i) a majority in the Senate declaring the Supreme Commander (Chancellor) to be unfit to issue orders, or (ii) the Security Council declaring him or her to be unfit to issue orders, and an authenticated order being received by the GAR, commanders shall be authorized to detain the Supreme Commander, with lethal force if necessary, and command of the GAR shall fall to the acting Chancellor until a successor is appointed or alternative authority identified as outlined in Section 6 (iv)."
> - **Order 66**: "In the event of Jedi officers acting against the interests of the Republic, and after receiving specific orders verified as coming directly from the Supreme Commander (Chancellor), GAR commanders will remove those officers by lethal force, and command of the GAR will revert to the Supreme Commander (Chancellor) until a new command structure is established."